# .NET Frameworkのバージョンに依る描画の違い

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

.NET Frameworkの4.0と4.5、さらには4.6で描画処理が異なるように見えるのですが。いまひとつ何が異なるのか判然としません。
どのような相違があるか、ご存じないでしょうか。

Answer (score 5):

WPF ではバージョンごとに .NET Framework のアップデートによって内部の描画処理が変更ないし新機能が追加されています。

例えば…
WPF 4.6: 高 DPI 時のレイアウトの丸め処理変更
WPF 4.5: 仮想化パネルのスクロール単位を制御するプロパティ追加（`VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit`）
などです。

高解像度環境を利用していると特にレイアウトの丸め処理変更による見た目の変化を感じる場合が多いと思われます。

参考：
http://grabacr.net/archives/5341